Does it make sense for a US citizen permanently living in a high tax country to use FEIE rather than FTC?
I live at least 10 months of the year in my home country, outside of the US. I work locally and have family here as well.
From my understanding, as long as I pay more taxes in my home country than would be charged in the US, I can exclude my income under FTC. The benefit of excluding under FTC is that I can exclude more than the FEIE limit (as of now $120K) and I can purchase a Roth IRA (as per hrblock).
Am I missing something? Is there any reason why a resident of a high tax country should exclude any of their income under FEIE?

Note that even when you use FEIE, you can still use FTC on taxes on the part of the income that is over the FEIE limit, or income that cannot be excluded by FEIE.

There may be such reasons. FEIE reduces taxable income on your US tax return and reduces the AGI. That can help for certain needs, although for many things MAGI is used bringing the excluded amounts back in. One example would be State taxes - in states which conform to the Federal tax law, AGI is the starting point, but they may not have tax credits for foreign taxes paid.
Everyone should evaluate their own situation and compare the calculations using both the FEIE and the FTC, and choose what works best for them. It's important to know that once FEIE chosen, it must be used for all the following years unless it is explicitly revoked.

I didn't notice that once I use FEIE, I have to explicitly revoke it in order to use something else.

You can still use ftc for amounts not excluded, but you'll have to continue excluding earned income until you revoke.

I don't earn $7k from non-earned income. It doesn't look like it's too bad to exclude. The one issue being that I can't exclude for the next 5 years. But that shouldn't be an issue for me, as I don't expect to move to a place with low taxes in the next 5 years.
